# Poor aesthetic judgement

Tags: idioms, expressions, idiomatic-language, idiom-request

Is there a way to say that someone has a very poor aesthetic judgement?

For example, you go to a house and you think everything is tacky or just ugly. How can you call the owner of the house?

I tend to say something like "This person has such a bad taste" or "This person has a very poor taste". But I don't know whether that means what I actually want to mean.

I know that *in poor taste* and *in bad taste* typically mean something that was done was offensive.

Comment: You could say ***He has no [sense of style.***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fashion-sense) That would often imply that even he himself would admit that he has little knowledge or interest in matters of fashion / aesthetics. But often if you say someone "has poor/bad taste", this might imply that even though they ***do*** have (possibly quite strong) opinions of such matters, ***you disagree with their opinions, and think they make bad choices anyway***.

Comment: Saying someone has bad taste is perfectly acceptable in this instance.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The second is what I meant. Someone with strong opinion but that I disagree in general with his/her choices.

Comment: *They have very poor aesthetic judgment.* There is nothing wrong with that statement. (In your original, there should be no article.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "They have poor taste."
>
> "They have no sense of style."
>
> "They have a bad eye." (usually a bad eye *for* something, like design or detail)

Each of these can be used in your context. They are not exact idioms, so they can be slightly modified. For example, these alternatives work just as well:

> "Horrible taste."
>
> "Unfortunate sense of style."
>
> "No eye for interior design.